# How can I have logcat window not on top of other windows

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

Is there some way of having the logcat window not being always on top?
I seldom have a use of such windows, and I cannot find a reason logcat would be an exception.

Comment: just minimize it, then click on it, it will hover, if you click outside it, it will disappear

Comment: The minimize button is disabled.

Comment: are you using Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, will that be a problem?

Comment: I use Eclipse too and it is docked. when I right click I see close in the menu which will hide it.

Comment: But I want the logcat window to be on its own.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Oh, what you will see if a window that is on top of other windows and cannot be brought below them...

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the Eclipse and drag logcat outside the Eclipse

Comment: If I minimize eclipse, logcat will be minimized as well.

Comment: sorry. I meant "Restore Down". thin you can close logcat

Comment: I still want the logcat window to be open. Not to close it.

Comment: But you can drag it away :)

Comment: I am not sure how to do what you describe, seems like a trick anyway. :)

Comment: I meant will be like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/Capture.JPG but you also can minimize all windows https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/Capture1.JPG to be like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/Capture2.JPG

Comment: Do you have a screenshot where the logcat window is below the eclipse window?

Comment: No, like if a window is covering another. It is on the same place but stacked so you can navigate to it with alt-tab.

Comment: Why you didn't like this style? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/Capture3.JPG the logcat minimized at the right of the eclipse

Comment: Because I am not like you?

Comment: lol ... in the previouse style you can maximize the logcat anytime you want. However, so what about this style? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/Capture4.JPG

Comment: What a good thing that you have found a way of working that suits you!

Comment: The default layout :) . But I like minimize the logcat and maximize it when i want to use it ... lol

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement that you run logcat through eclipse at all - you can run `adb logcat` from the command line shell of your host operating system.  This also allows you to capture the output, make interesting filters with `grep` and so on.

The location of the adb executable has changed in different releases of the android tools; currently it's in the platform-tools/ directory of the installation, so if that is not in your path you will have to explicitly specify the location.

Comment: Oh, but I like the gui, it is just a strange thing that I cannot handle the window as I am used to handle windows.

Comment: You are welcome to like it (and wrestle with it) then - just stating that there are options.